# vba search range for value, if value exists change each value?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet like so:

```
Column D        Column G

1               #VALUE!
2               #VALUE!
#VALUE!         3
```

I am trying to search my range for the value #VALUE!.

Where this value is found i want to change each occurrence of #VALUE! to TBC.

Here's my code:

```
    Range("D30:G39").Select
                    Set cell = Selection.Find(What:="#VALUE!", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                    If cell Is Nothing Then
                    'do it something
                    Else

For Each Cell.Value
                    cell.value = "TBC"
Next Cell
'End For

                    wStemplaTE.Range("A41").value = "Please fill in the pallet factor and case size accordingly. Please amend total volume if necessary to accommodate full pallets."
                    End If
```

I need to try and create a loop so that each cell value is changed to TBC.

I'm brand new to VBA and not quite sure how i would do this.

Please can someone point me in the right direction / show me how to do this correctly? Thanks

EDIT:

For Each Cell.Value <--- This line highlights in red as not formatted correctly? Any ideas?

Comment: Try lookat xlPart

Comment: Why not use Find and Replace?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav : Nah, the issue here is `LookIn:=xlFormulas`, but it should be `xlValues`

Comment: I wrote `Cells.Find(What:="#ref", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=   False, SearchFormat:=False)` and worked fine

Comment: @Nathan_Sav can you tell me what you wrote for this line: For Each Cell.Value? this line says it's not formatted correctly and highlights red

Comment: @user7415328 you have been living of the "answers" you got on this site. Find the time to give proper feedback to people who answered this post of yours. You should mark one of the answers below as "Answer" (you know how)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim Cel, Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range("D30:G39")

For Each Cel In Rng
    If Err.Number = 13 Then Cel.Value = "TBC"
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: does it matter that "#VALUE!" is a value and not an error? The values in this range have been copied from another spreadsheet - which produced the original error

Comment: VBA recognises "#VALUE!" as an error (as opposed to an absolute value) - I think this is due to the `#` prefix (but not certain)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proper way to use `Range.Find` method, that you should use every time :

(BTW, I already answered you some times ago with such a structure in a bigger chunk of code)

```
Sub test_user7415328()
Dim FirstAddress As String, cF As Range, LookForString As String
LookForString = "#VALUE!"

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet's name").Range("D30:G39")
    .Cells(1, 1).Activate
    'First, define properly the Find method
    Set cF = .Find(What:=LookForString, _
                After:=ActiveCell, _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, _
                SearchFormat:=False)

    'If there is a result, store the address of the 1st one
    If Not cF Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = cF.Address
        Do
            'Do your actions
            cF.Value = "TBC"
            'Keep looking with FindNext method
            Set cF = .FindNext(cF)
        'Look until you find again the first result
        Loop While Not cF Is Nothing And cF.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the Cell's value equals `CVErr(xlErrValue)`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReplaceErrVal()

Dim C As Range

For Each C In Range("D30:G39")
    On Error Resume Next
    If C.Value = CVErr(xlErrValue) Then
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            On Error GoTo 0
        Else
            C.Value = "TBC"
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Range("D30:G39").Replace what:="#VALUE!", Replacement:="TBC", lookat:=xlWhole
```

Comment: @user7415328, did you try this?